# Enter parameter value error in vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a simple VBA code that makes me update a database table with update statement .
the field I want to update is date/time so the code I use is :

```
Public myDate, renewalDate As Date
Public Sub Renewal()
renewalDate = DLookup("renewalDate", "tblDate", "[id]=1")
Dim newDate As Date
Serial = "123456789"
If Forms![frmRenewal]![txtSerial] = Serial Then
    newDate = DateAdd("m", 1, renewalDate)
    MsgBox newDate
    DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
    DoCmd.RunSQL "Update tblDate SET tblDate.renewalDate = newDate WHERE (((tblDate.id)=1))"
    MsgBox "You successfully renewed your subscription and renewal date is now " & renewalDate
Else
    MsgBox "Wrong Serial"
End If
End sub
```

and here is the database table:

[image]

and I get this error when I run the code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your variable `newDate` is defined within the scope of the VBA subroutine `Renewal` and has no meaning within the SQL statement executed by the `RunSQL` method, therefore causing the SQL engine to interpret it as a parameter requiring a value.

Whilst you could concatenate the value of this variable as part of the SQL statement supplied to the `RunSQL` method, a cleaner approach might be to perform the calculation of the new date directly within the SQL statement, e.g.:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "update tblDate set tblDate.renewalDate = DateAdd(""m"", 1, tblDate.renewalDate) where tblDate.id = 1"
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation it works now after i used your solution .... many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it to:

```vb
Public myDate As Date, renewalDate As Date

Public Sub Renewal()

    Serial = "123456789"
    If Forms![frmRenewal]![txtSerial] = Serial Then
        renewalDate = DateAdd("m", 1, renewalDate)
        CurrentDb.Execute "Update tblDate SET renewalDate = DateAdd('m', 1, [renewalDate]) WHERE id = 1"
        MsgBox "You successfully renewed your subscription, and renewal date is now " & renewalDate
    Else
        MsgBox "Wrong Serial"
    End If

End sub
```